Does RCCB have 1P+N and 2P types? Why?
as per my understanding
The letter 'P' in 1P+N and 2P indicates how many wires the device will protect from overload and short circuit
RCCB device only includes the function of electric shock protection
So I think RCCB will not come with the concept of 1P+N and 2P right?
